# How to compare datetime objects in python?

Tags: python, datetime, timezone, pytz

Okay never had something as hard as datetimes in Python. I'got a time, `my_time` and this time always needs be added 2 hours to it during summer and 1 hour during winter. The correct timezone for `my_time` is EET. Now Im trying to compare it with `start_time` and `end_time` but I can see its still looking to the 'base' `my_time` when executing the if statement. How is that possible?

**This is my code:**

```
my_time = '20200907-07u00m00s' 
my_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(my_time, '%Y%m%d-%Hu%Mm%Ss')   
timezone= 'Europe/Amsterdam'
my_time = pytz.utc.localize(my_time).astimezone(pytz.timezone(timezone))

start_time = '202097060000'
start_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(start_time, '%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
start_time = pytz.utc.localize(start_time)

end_time = '202097080000'
end_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(end_time, '%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
end_time = pytz.utc.localize(end_time)

if my_time >= start_time and my_time <= end_time: 
    print('my_time IS between the start and end time')
else:
    print('my_time IS NOT between the start and end time')
```

**The received output:**
`my_time IS between the start and end time`

I guess the code is checking if  `2020-09-07 07:00:00` is between `2020-09-07 06:00:00` and `2020-09-07 08:00:00`....

**My expected output is that the code checks if:**
`2020-09-07 09:00:00` is between `2020-09-07 06:00:00` and `2020-09-07 08:00:00` and that means it should print `my_time IS NOT between the start and end time`

Comment: both start_time and end_time are in UTC while my_time is local time (UTC+2). the comparison takes the UTC offset into account, so `2020-09-07 09:00:00+02:00` falls between  `2020-09-07 06:00:00+00:00` and `2020-09-07 08:00:00+00:00`.

Comment: @MrFuppes Yes I know, thats what I said in my question also, but I want `my_time` to be `2020-09-07 09:00:00` and not `2020-09-07 09:00:00+02:00`

Comment: Then you shouldn't localize to the time zone but UTC (as you do for start- and end-time).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get the UTC-offset of the localized `my_time` value and add it to `my_time`:

```
my_time = '20200907-07u00m00s' 
my_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(my_time, '%Y%m%d-%Hu%Mm%Ss')   

timezone= 'Europe/Amsterdam'
my_time_tz = pytz.utc.localize(my_time).astimezone(pytz.timezone(timezone))

timeDiff = my_time_tz.utcoffset().total_seconds()
print("UTC Offset: %s seconds" % timeDiff)
normalized_my_time = pytz.utc.localize(my_time+datetime.timedelta(seconds=timeDiff))

start_time = '202097060000'
start_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(start_time, '%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
start_time = pytz.utc.localize(start_time)

end_time = '202097080000'
end_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(end_time, '%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
end_time = pytz.utc.localize(end_time)

print(start_time , normalized_my_time , end_time)

if start_time <= normalized_my_time <= end_time: 
    print('my_time IS between the start and end time')
else:
    print('my_time IS NOT between the start and end time')
```

Out:

```
UTC Offset: 7200.0 seconds
2020-09-07 06:00:00+00:00 2020-09-07 09:00:00+00:00 2020-09-07 08:00:00+00:00
my_time IS NOT between the start and end time
```

Comment: @MrFuppes: OP said in the comments: *but I want my_time to be 2020-09-07 09:00:00*. In the end all 3 datetimes should either be localized or UTC.

Comment: yeah, I still don't get why it's localized to a certain time zone in the first place.

Comment: @MauriceMeyer Mind If we pm about this subject?